# What's the content of the XMLDSIG DigestMethod element?

Tags: xml, digital-signature, xml-signature

The XMLDSIG-CORE spec defines the DigestMethod element in a Reference.  The DigestMethod specifies the Algorithm that should be applied to the referenced document to obtain the DigestValue.

What I don't get, is why this DigestMethod has this for its content (in XML schema):

```
<sequence>
<any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</sequence>
```

What's the point of this content, and how should I interprete it should I receive it?

Answer (score -1):

Check RFC 3075 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3075.txt -- The value depends on what you have on 'Reference'

There are 3 types of XML Digital Signature: Enveloped, Enveloping and Detached. First identify which one are you working on. As an example, if you are in the enveloped signature case, and your URL of Reference is empty, the digest correspond to the digest of the canonicalization version of your XML without the 'Signature' node. Again, there are several versions of canonicalization, so you have to check in your XML which one is this referring to.

It should not be difficult to calculate, but you need to pay attention to this details before attempting to calculate or figure out where this value comes from.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't explain what the content of a digestmethod is.